# Ruby on Rails 3 : Playing with session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning to create user sign in and sign up.
Here is my html code for sign in,

```
<% if signed_in? %>  
  <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete %></li>  
<% else %>  
  <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

But when I am success sign in, the `Sign out` doesn't show up.

Someone help me please? :D

Here is my `signed_in?` code in SessionHelper

## Update 1

```
module SessionsHelper  
  def sign_in(user)  
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]  
    self.current_user = user  
  end  
  def current_user=(user)  
    @current_user = user  
  end
  def current_user  
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token  
  end
  def signed_in?  
    !current_user.nil?  
  end
  def sign_out  
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)  
    self.current_user = nil  
  end  
  def deny_access  
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."  
  end  
  def current_user?(user)  
    user == current_user  
  end  
  def redirect_back_or(default)  
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)  
    clear_return_to  
  end  

private  
  def user_from_remember_token  
    User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)  
  end  
  def remember_token  
    cookies.signed[:remembered_token] || [nil, nil]  
  end  
  def store_location  
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath  
  end  
  def clear_return_to  
    session[:return_to] = nil  
  end  
end
```

Here is my SessionController

## Update 2

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController  
def new  
  @title = "Sign In"  
end  
def create  
  user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])  
  if user.nil?  
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."  
  @title = "Sign in"  
  render 'new'  
else  
  sign_in user  
  redirect_to user  
end  
end  
def destroy  
  sign_out  
  redirect_to root_path  
end  
end
```

Comment: can you post your code for the `signed_in?` method please?

Comment: When I am sign in, the browser took me to the user profile.  
But the menu `sign out` doesn't show up to replace the `sign in`.
Please see my #update 2 for the SessionsController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SessionsHelper, change

```
def remember_token
  cookies.signed[:remembered_token] || [nil, nil]
end
```

to

```
def remember_token
  cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
end
```

Many thanks for your support. :D